# Karma chrome debug mode: duplicate js files loaded in browser (with & without js extension)

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, karma-runner

We have return spec files to execute test cases. few files for example client.ts is imported in multiple files.
while running karma in debug mode, in browsers sources section i am able to see two files with same path **'../somepath/client'** & **'../somepath/client.js'**.
so we are getting 2 instances of client object causing problems in running test cases.
(we are overriding(mocking) few methods from client.ts file).

What is this phenomenon.Has anyone faced this issue.